# Gradle: Error while uploading app-local-debug.apk : Unknown failure ([CDS]close[0])

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, automated-tests, android-espresso

I am trying to use gradlew cAT command to perform the connected android tests with my android phone. But i get the below Error log and it cannot install the app.

- The App gets installed if adb command is used.
- The above command works ok with OnePlusOne phones but not in Lenovo and Asus

The error log is  below:

```
Unable to install /home/admin/MyApp/app/build/outputs/apk/app-local-debug.apk
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to install all 
        at com.android.ddmlib.SplitApkInstaller.install(SplitApkInstaller.java:91)
        at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackages(Device.java:901)
        at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackages(ConnectedDevice.java:119)
        at com.android.builder.internal.testing.SimpleTestCallable.call(SimpleTestCallable.java:121)
        at com.android.builder.internal.testing.SimpleTestCallable.call(SimpleTestCallable.java:48)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 35):

This happens to be a very common problem with most Chinese manufactured phones. The issue lies within your gradle-plugin dependencies and there are two ways you can go about solving it.

#### Option 1: Downgrade your gradle version.

Step 1: go to `sampleProject/android/build.gradle` at line 8 and Modify classpath to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3` or 1.2.1.

Step 2: go to `sampleProject/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` at line 5 and Modify distributionUrl to `https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2-all.zip`

#### Option 2: Install manually

Step 1: Locate the app-debug.apk at `sampleProject/android/app/build/outputs/apk`. 

Step 2:Copy and Paste into any folder in your phone then click to install it. 

Step 3: Shake your phone to expose settings, click on **Dev Settings** then  **Debug Server host & port for device** and configure it with your ip address(192.168.xx.xx:8081).
 Start your react-native server and viola you are up and running!!!

**EDIT!!!!!!!!**
 

Doing either option listed above became so tiring and frustrating and I found another solution.

#### Option 3: Add device Id

Step 1: Make sure your device is connected and then run `adb devices`. From the output, grab the device id H80xxxxxx.

Step 2: Run `react-native run-android --deviceId H80xxxxxx`

---

NB: Personally I now use option 3 any time the error pops up!!

Comment: the first option worked for me, but you need to run this command too: `cd android && gradlew clean && cd .. && react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

Check using `adb devices` if your phones are correctly seen

If yes, try using `adb` to install app on your phone, if it is installed and works fine than run the tests using `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest`(on linux).

According to issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2720

It may be a problem with Gradle plugin version, so if you still face the problem downgrade your gradle-plugin dependencies.

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Issue is because you might have `connected both Emulator & Real device`. Remove one them you should be good to go.

Since i had the same issue after removing my real device it fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled the apk from my device.After doing that My issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
My solution: delete the `app-local-debug.apk` or `app-debug.apk` file manually and run it again